# Did Wrath actually love his wife?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In *Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood*, among the Homunculi, Wrath said that he chose his wife himself. Everything else was given to him. So did Wrath actually love his wife?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that he *didn't*?

Comment: Well you could ask: "Since the Homunculis were Father's vices, and none of the other Homunculi displayed love towards another being, does that mean Wrath was faking his love for his wife?" The answer is quite simple anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot....the only emotion in wrath was wrath...so i had a doubt

Comment: I think that he did. It's implied that she was the only person (and thing) he ever cared about in his life, since he did get to choose her.